# How do I write text on the right side of my table?

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c|cc|c}
    &    &  $x_1$ &  $x_2$ 

&\multirow{6}{*}{The most negative among $x_{Bi}, i=1,\ldots,4$ 
    is -2. So $x_3$ will leave the basis.$\mbox{max}\Bigg\{\frac{z_j}{a_{sj}}|a_{3j}<0\Bigg\}=\mbox{max}\Bigg\{\frac{3}{-2}, \frac{1}{-3}\Bigg\}=-\frac{1}{-3}$  . So $x_2$ 
is entered into the basis. The pivot element is -3.} \\

\cline{1-4}
$z$   &   0 &  3   &   1  &\\
\cline{1-4}
$x_1$ &  0  &  -1   &   0  &\\
$x_2$ &  0  &   0   &   -1  &\\
$x_3$ &  -2 &  -2   &  -3 & \\
$x_4$ &  -1 &  -1   &   -1  &\\
\cline{1-4}

\end{tabular}
\caption{}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I want the text "The most....element is -3" to be wrapped on the right side of my table. And the caption to be exactly below my table

[image: I want the text "The most....element is -3" to be wrapped on the right side of my table. And the caption to be exactly below my table]

Comment: Seems like a minipage and `\captionof{table}{the caption}` might help you here.

Answer (score 5):

I tweaked the output a little bit, using an `array` as suggested
by @Mico. As seen in @Bernard's answer, you can use package
`booktabs` to give the tabular material a more pleasing look.

Have a look at @Bernards answer and the definition of the set
command. I used a bit of package `physics` hackery.

Judging from your use of `[h!]` i think you don't want your table
to float at all. So i simply used two minipages here. You can add
a little more space by surrounding it with a `center`
environment. You can still surround it with a table if you want
to. You don't have to use `captionof` then.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{capt-of}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}


    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.30\linewidth}
    \begin{math}
    \begin{array}{crrr}
      &    & x_1 & x_2 \\
  \cmidrule(lr){3-4}
  z   & 0  & 3   & 1  \\
  \midrule
  x_1 & 0  & -1  & 0  \\
  x_2 & 0  & 0   & -1  \\
  x_3 & -2 & -2  & -3  \\
  x_4 & -1 & -1  & -1  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{array}
    \end{math}
    \captionof{table}{}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.65\linewidth}
    The most negative among
    $x_{Bi}, i=1,\ldots,4$ 
    is $-2$. So $x_3$ will leave the basis. 
    \[
    \max\qty{\frac{z_j}{a_{sj}}\Big\vert a_{3j}<0}=
    \max\qty{\frac{3}{-2},
    \frac{1}{-3}}=-\frac{1}{-3}
    \]
    So $x_2$ is entered into the basis. The
    pivot element is $-3$.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: btw: is there any reason for making the braces so big?

Comment: There is a `sidecap` package, but it's quite old

Comment: Some suggestions for code clean-up: Since the material in the `tabular` consists entirely of math terms (including some negative numbers), it would be useful to use an `array` environment instead of a `tabular`; replace `\cline{1-4}` with `\hline`; put the terms `-2` and `-3` on the right-hand size into math mode; and use `\big` instead of `\Bigg` to size the curly braces.

Comment: @Mico Thanks, haven't really looked at the contents. I just put minipages there ;-) I added some stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You can get what you want with a `wraptable` environment. I used an `array` environment (with `r` specifier for a better alignment of numbers with a minus sign), deleted the vertical lines, and used the `booktabs`, so as to have variable thickness for horizontal rules, and less tight vertical spacing. Also, I used the `nccmath` package for  its `medium-sized fractions` (and more generally its medium-sized maths, which is about `80 %` of display style, more appropriate in this context). The `caption` package automatically removes the `colon` separator between label and text of a caption if there is no text.

Finally, I defined a `\set` command (adapted from an example in the `mathtools` documentation). It has `one` argument. For set-builder notation, set members and defining properties are separated by a `semi-colon`. It results in a much lighter TeX notation that is very close to what one writes by hand.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption}
\captionsetup{font=small, labelfont=sc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\set}[1]\{\}{\setargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m}
{\setargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargsaux}{mm}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1}{\nonscript\,#1\nonscript\;\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:\allowbreak #2\nonscript\,}}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\setlength\columnsep{2em}

\begin{document}

\begin{wraptable}{l}{0pt}
$ \begin{array}{crrr}
    & & x_1 & x_2 \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
 z & 0 & 3 & 1 \\
\toprule
 x_1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 x_2 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 x_3 & -2 & -2 & -3 \\
 x_4 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{array} $
\caption{}
\end{wraptable}
The most negative among $x_{Bi}, i=1,\ldots,4$ is $ -2 $. So $x_3$ will leave the basis.
\[ \max\set[\Big]{\mfrac{z_j}{a_{sj}}; a_{3j} < 0 }=\max\set[\Big]{\mfrac{3}{-2}, \mfrac{1}{-3}}=-\mfrac{1}{3}. \]
So $x_2$ is entered into the basis. The pivot element is $ -3 $.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want exactly what you have compiled but when I run the commands the code "\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\set}[1]\{\}{\setargs{#1}}" shows "undefined control sequence" error. What should I do?

Comment: @Agog: Did you load `mathtools` and `xparse`? And did you check you have sufficiently recent versions of these packages? Perhaps you should update.